# unity cannot implicitly convert type float' to bool' also Make the camera zoom?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, zooming

I use C# and I'm new.  I am trying to make a zoom function for a game on unity.  Here is my code (that I have so far):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Zoom : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Camera cam;
    public float zoom_speed = 20f;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {
        if(Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel"))
        {
            cam.fieldOfView = zoom_speed;
        }
    }
}
```

However, I am getting the error "cannot implicitly convert type **float** to **bool** when I hover over `if(Input.GetAxis("Mouse Scrollwheel"))` Also any advice on how to make the zoom program work would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel");` script return a float value.

> The value will be in the range -1...1 for keyboard and joystick input.
>   If the axis is setup to be delta mouse movement, the mouse delta is
>   multiplied by the axis sensitivity and the range is not -1...1.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Zoom : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Camera cam;
    public float zoom_speed = 20f;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {
         float d = Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel");
         if (d > 0f)
         {
            //Positive value
            //Scroll up
            cam.fieldOfView += zoom_speed;
         }
         else if (d < 0f)
         {
            //Negative value
            //Scroll down
            cam.fieldOfView -= zoom_speed;
         }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Complementing the answer from 0xBFE1A8, you don't even need to use a **if...else** statement because the value will be in the range **-1...1**, just multiply the `Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel")` value by the zoom_speed. I also suggest you to clamp the field of view between a minimum and maximum values defined by you.

```
float scroll = Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel");
cam.fieldOfView = Mathf.Clamp(cam.fieldOfView + zoom_speed * scroll * Time.deltaTime, minFieldOfView, maxFieldOfView);
```